# How do I hide the quantity box in bundle product page?

Tags: css, bundled-product, quantity

Basically I've already set default quantity(1) for the linked product in the bundle product display page, now I just want to hide the quantity selection for the linked product all together. Appreciate any pointers. thanks

Comment: What version of Magento are you on?

Comment: Welcome to the community please put some images also with your question so that someone can better help you with the thing you exactly wanted

Moreover you can make quantity field to be readonly. So the user will not be able to make changes into it.

Answer (score 0):

Bundled products have their own .phtml file for displaying the product in Magento 2.

Simply edit the .phtml file in a child theme